# Hide admin notices/notifications from everyone but super admin?

Tags: customization

I have a Multisite setup, and I would like to hide all notices/notifications from the admin pages for everyone but me (the Super Admin).
How would I manage to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code in your custom plugin which is better to activate for the network.

```
if ( !is_super_admin() ) {
    remove_all_actions('admin_notices');
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that hide notices for the super admin only?

Comment: it will hide notices for everyone except superadmin

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd share in case it helps someone else.

Notices are added by the following actions (in this order):

- `network_admin_notices` (for network admin--aka super admin. You don't want to remove these.)
- `user_admin_notices` (for site admin)
- `admin_notices` (for other users)

The last action to be run before these is `in_admin_header` so that would be the best place to hook into to remove the notices.

```
function my_hide_notices_to_all_but_super_admin(){
     if (!is_super_admin()) {
         remove_all_actions( 'user_admin_notices' );
         remove_all_actions( 'admin_notices' );
     }
}
add_action('in_admin_header', 'my_hide_notices_to_all_but_super_admin', 99);
```

I'm using a high priority of 99 to make it unlikely that notices get added in after this runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this function in the functions.php file of your theme.

```
function hide_update_noticee_to_all_but_admin_users()
{
    if (!is_super_admin()) {
        remove_all_actions( 'admin_notices' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_noticee_to_all_but_admin_users', 1 );
```

Comment: Better to put this in a code snippet or plugin that only runs on the backend for logged in users. (As opposed to tying it to a theme.)